# Button click Triggers Text Below

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, button

I want to set up a functionality for a button that causes text to appear underneath it on click.

For example, when you click a button that says "Sign up now", text would appear underneath the button that says "Are you a member, yes or no?".

"Yes" and "No" would be links that bring you to a different page depending on how you answer.

My button code so far (just html and styling done):

```
<a href="/ticket-link" target="_blank" class="ticket-button">Sign Up  
Now</a>
```

I'm new with this kind of functionality so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the `href` attribute as you want.

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('#modal').fadeIn();
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#modal {
  width: 300px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: none;
}

#modal h3 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

#modal a {
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 10px;
}

.btns {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/ticket-link" target="_blank" class="ticket-button" id='btn'>Sign Up Now</a>

<div id='modal'>
  <h3>Are you a member?</h3>
  <div class='btns'>
    <a href="/ticket-link" target="_blank" class="ticket-button">Yes</a>
    <a href="/ticket-link" target="_blank" class="ticket-button">No</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the onClick function to unhide text, or elements, below it.

```
<a href="/ticket-link" onClick='document.getElementById("text").style.display="initial";' target="_blank" class="ticket-button">Sign Up Now</a>
<span style="display:none;" id="text">This is some text :D</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple way:

```
<a href="/ticket-link" target="_blank" class="ticket-button" onclick="confirmSignup()">Sign Up Now</a>

<script>
function confirmSignup(){
  if(confirm("Are you sure?"))
  {
    window.location.href="http://somelocation.com/sign-up";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Pety Howell said, you can use the onClick function to unhide the text. Here's a pretty straightforward way to do it with jQuery.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.link').on('click', function() {
     $('.span').addClass('open');
      });
});
```

```css
.span {
  display: none;
}
.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="link">Click me</a>
<span class="span">I'm hidden!</span>
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3gr03yzn/4/

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function.

HTML :

```
<button id="member">
Are you Member ?
</button>

<div class="answer">
<a href="#">Yes</a><br />
<a href="#">No</a>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$("#member").click(function() {
   $(".answer").toggle();
});
```

CSS :

```
.answer {
  display:none;
}
```

The [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/5wzczxtx/) on jsFiddle.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
**please vote if this code helpful to you**

```js
function execute(){
        var x =  document.getElementById('link_list');
        var y =document.getElementById('btn');
        if(x.style.visibility==="hidden"){
            y.style.visibility="hidden";
            x.style.visibility="visible";
        }
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="execute()" id="btn">sign up</button>
<div id="link_list" style="visibility:hidden">
Are you a member, <button onclick="window.open('http://sparrolite.blogspot.in')">Yes</button>&nbsp;or &nbsp;<button onclick="window.open('google.com')">no</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most answers mentioned here either uses

1. jQuery or,
2. `onclick` attribute which is [obtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Here's how to achieve the desired behavior using **vanilla**, **unobtrusive** JavaScript.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var button = document.querySelector('.ticket-button');
  var info = document.querySelector('.info');

  info.style.display = 'none';
  var dispalyInfo = false;

  button.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); /* prevent page from navigating to a new page onclick */
    if (dispalyInfo) {
      info.style.display = 'none';
      dispalyInfo = false;
    } else {
      info.style.display = 'initial';
      dispalyInfo = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.ticket-button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="/ticket-link" target="_blank" class="ticket-button">Sign Up Now</a>
<span class="info">Are you a member, <a href="#">yes</a> or <a href="#">no</a>?</span>
```

References:

- [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)